# React Native - react-native-exception-handler doesn't catch error thrown inside a promise

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

My react native application is running on android virtual device (API 23). I'm using react-native-exception-handler for the purpose of handling all errors that occur in one place. But react-native-exception-handle is only catching the simple errors, errors thrown from inside a promise are ignored. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Android Gradle Plugin Version - 7.2.0
Gradle Version - 7.4.2

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
...

}
```

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  View,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import { setJSExceptionHandler } from 'react-native-exception-handler';

const errorHandler = (e, isFatal) => {
    if (isFatal) {
      Alert.alert(
          'Unexpected error occurred',
          `
          Error: ${(isFatal) ? 'Fatal:' : ''} ${e.name} ${e.message}
  
          We have reported this to our team ! Please close the app and start again!
          `,
        [{
          text: 'Close'
        }]
      );
    } else {
      console.log(e); 
    }
};
  
setJSExceptionHandler(errorHandler, true);

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    causeJSError () {
        throw new Error('THIS IS A CUSTOM UNHANDLED JS ERROR');
    }

    causeJSPromiseError () {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            throw new Error("Whoops!"); 
        }).catch(error => {
            throw error;
        });
    }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={this.causeJSError.bind(this)} title="CAUSE JS ERROR" color="#841584" style={{flex:1}}/>     
        <Button onPress={this.causeJSPromiseError.bind(this)} title="CAUSE JS PROMISE ERROR" color="#841584" style={{flex:1}}/>     
    </View>
    );
 }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
  });
```

Below the app screen

[image]

If the "CAUSE JS ERROR" button is pressed to throw the simple error, the global exception handler works normally and shows the custom error screen as below

[image]

Otherwise if the "CAUSE JS PROMISE ERROR" button is pressed to throw an exception from inside a promise, the global exception handler doesn't work and the custom error screen is not shown. Just the information in the log as below

```
 LOG  Running "handlertest" with {"rootTag":21}
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Whoops!
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:112203:26
tryCallTwo@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:28940:9
doResolve@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:29104:25
Promise@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:28963:14
causeJSPromiseError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:112202:20
causeJSPromiseError@[native code]
_performTransitionSideEffects@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:65273:22
_receiveSignal@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:65215:45
onResponderRelease@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:65055:34
invokeGuardedCallbackProd@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3940:21
invokeGuardedCallback@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:4044:42
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:4048:36
executeDispatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:4124:48
executeDispatchesInOrder@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:4144:26
executeDispatchesAndRelease@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:5493:35
forEach@[native code]
forEachAccumulated@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:4674:22
runEventsInBatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:5517:27
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:5597:25
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:5572:42
batchedUpdates$1@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:17982:20
batchedUpdates@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:5479:36
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:5571:23
receiveTouches@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:5625:34
__callFunction@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3057:36
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2781:31
__guard@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3008:15
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.handlertest&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2780:21
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

Comment: This is happening to me just in Android. The lib has not been updated since March 23, 2021. The most recent articles about error handling in react don't mention 'react-native-exception-handler' - only use React Native error boundaries (even with limitations).